# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0-'

Tags: python, valueerror

The question was to create an encryption system to encrypt the letters of the alphabet and space. The method was as follows.

1)Choose two primes p and q. Then calculate another two integers n and k as follows. n = p*q and k = (p-1)(q-1).

2) Chose another integer e such that e is relatively prime with both (p-1) and (q-1).[Two numbers are relatively prime if their greatest common divisor is 1.]

3) Calculate integer d as the smallest number which satisfy (e*d-1)%k = 0

4) Assign two digit integers to English alphabet.[E.g.: A-00, B-01, C-02,...,Z-25,' '-26]

5) Then convert the message into digits by replacing characters with digits.

6) For each two digits calculate c = (two_digits)^e mod n. [e is same as e]

7) That creates the secret message.

8) To create decrypt the message take each two digits together from the secret text and then calculate (two_crypted_digits)^d mod n for each two digits seperately.

9) The resultant numbers can be reffered to the two digit representation of the numbers mentioned above.

My code runs in my laptop without any errors but when I try to evaluate the code using the Virtual Programming Lab of the university it gives the error mentioned.

Here's my code:

```
def read_input(file_name):                   
    f=open(file_name,'r')         
    message=f.read().split('\n')    
    p=message.pop(0)                
    q=message.pop(0)                
    e=message.pop(0)
    return p,q,e,message            

def is_prime(number):               
    count=0                         
    for i in range(1,number+1):    
        if number%i==0:             
            count=count+1
    if count==2:                    
        return True
    else:
        return False


def is_relatively_prime(number1,number2):   
    if is_prime(number2)==True:             
        x=min(number1,number2-1)            
        y=max(number1,number2)              
        a=[]
        if x==number1:                      
            for i in range(x,0,-1):             
                if x%i==0:
                     a.append(i)                
            for j in a:
                if (number2-1)%j==0:           
                    if j==1:
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
                    break
        else:
            for i in range(number2-1,0,-1):             
                if (number2-1)%i==0:
                    a.append(i)                
            for j in a:
                if number1%j==0:           
                    if j==1:
                        return True
                    else:
                        return False
                    break


    else:
         return False


def get_digits_from_char(letter):                                   
    if letter == " ":                                               
        string_digits = '26'
    else:                                                           
        letter = letter.upper()                                     
        ascii_val = ord(letter)                                     
        temp_string_digits = ascii_val - 65                         
        if temp_string_digits >=10:                                 
            string_digits = str(temp_string_digits)                 
        else:
            string_digits = '0'+str(temp_string_digits)            
    return string_digits                                            

def char_from_digits(two_digits):                                   
    if two_digits == "26":                                         
        character = ' '
    else:                                                           
         temp_digits = int(two_digits)                               
         ascii_digits = 65 + temp_digits                             
         character = chr(ascii_digits)                               
    return character                                                

def get_d(e,k):                                                     
    for i in range(2,(k+1)):                                       
        if ((e * i - 1) % k) == 0:                                  
            d = i                                                   
            break                                                   
     return d                                                        

def get_two_digit_representation(message):                          
    string = ''                                                     
    for letter in message:                                          
        string = string + get_digits_from_char(letter)              
    return string                                                   

 def get_secret_message(digit_message,e,n):                                      
        secret_message=''                                                           
    a=''
    b=''                                                                        
    digmsg_lis=list(digit_message)                                              
    for i in range(len(digit_message)/2):
        a=digmsg_lis.pop(0)
        b=digmsg_lis.pop(0)                                                    
        c=a+b
        sec_digit=(int(c)**int(e))%int(n)                                      
        if sec_digit<10:
            sec_digit='0'+str(sec_digit)                                        
            secret_message+=sec_digit
        else:
            secret_message+=str(sec_digit)
    return secret_message                                                       

def get_digit_message(secret_message,d,n):                                      
    digit_message=''                                                            
    a=''
    b=''                                                                        
    secdig_lis=list(secret_message)                                             
    for i in range(len(secret_message)/2):
        a=secdig_lis.pop(0)
        b=secdig_lis.pop(0)
        c=a+b                                                                  dig=(int(c)**int(d))%int(n)                                             
        if dig<10:
            dig='0'+str(dig)                                                  
            digit_message+=dig
        else:
            digit_message+=str(dig)
    return digit_message                                                        


def write_output (file_name,message_list):                                      
    f=open(file_name,'w')                                                       #open file as a writemode
    for x in message_list:                                                     
        f.write(str(x)+'\n')                                                    


p, q, e, messages = read_input(raw_input())
while is_prime(int(p)) and is_prime(int(q)) and is_relatively_prime(int(e),(int(p))) and is_relatively_prime(int(e),(int(q))):
    n = int(p)*int(q)
    k = (int(p)-1)*(int(q)-1)
    d = get_d(int(e),k)
    messages_list = []
    for message in messages:
        messages_list.append(get_secret_message(get_two_digit_representation(message),e,n))
    write_output('Output.txt',messages_list)
    break
```

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runProgram.py", line 12, in <module>
    import test
  File "/home/p13312/test.py", line 141, in <module>
    messages_list.append(get_secret_message(get_two_digit_representation(message),e,n))
  File "/home/p13312/test.py", line 102, in get_secret_message
    sec_digit=(int(c)**int(e))%int(n)                                       
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0-'
```

Comment: looks like your `get_two_digit_representation` function returns nonsense (`"0-"`). Have you done any debugging?

Comment: The code runs without a fuss in my laptop.